# Add javascript in Extended Menu (Joomla 3.2.2) (like DHTML menu in drupal)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal, joomla

I've got a problem in using Extended Menu. First, it's the only menu which allows the creation of a menu tree with categories (the only one free).

The major problem is that javascript is not enabled in Exented Menu, and the page reloads each time a click is performed on the menu.

So my question is : is there an easy solution to enable javascript with Extended Menu, in order to expand/collapse submenus without reloading the entire page.

I tried to install some templates of Extended Menu, but got an error in a php page... The major problem is that i'm not a joomla specialist, so i dunno which file to edit/add, and with which script, to perform the desire action !

In other words, I would like to make Extended Menu in `Joomla`, to work like `DHTML` menu in `Drupal`

Comment: Is Extended Menu an extension? If so then contact the developer

Comment: I tried, no response atm. But maybe someone add the same problem and found a solution, cause it's a popular extension on Joomla as i understand !